# JQuery Image Flip - Why does html image map with highlighting break it?

Tags: jquery, highlighting, imagemap, flip

Im using this jquery plug in: http://webmuch.com/image-flip-using-jquery/ to flip an html image map.  This works fine when I use an image map with no effects.

However,  I am using this plug in: http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/ to highlight parts of my image map (really nice plug in I might add).

Why do the 2 seem to be incompatible?  If I add the image map highlighting all sorts of crazy things happen with the flip.

Any thoughts?

I wont post the code since its quite big.

Comment: Can you upload a demo of the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The second plugin uses version 1.2.3 of jQuery, the first is new and uses 1.3.2. It could be a compatability issue between the versions.

Firstly I would try to get the second plugin working in isolation with 1.3.2. If you can we can then look at other possible issues.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many hot-spots are in your HTML Image Map you could go down a different route. Using only Images, HTML, CSS & core JQuery a really slim, elegant solution can be arrived at. I wrote about it here: [Revisiting the HTML Image Map](http://www.workwithchoicecuts.com/methodology/revisiting-the-html-image-map/)